# Translating plant names used attributively

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, adjective, modern-life, suffixes, neologism

In English and some other languages, a plant name (or a fruit name) can be used like an adjective ("attributively"), for example *apple juice*, *oak wood*, *birch bark*.

When translated into Latin, the plant part may become an adjective, like **querceus** for *of oak*, **rosaceus** for *made of rose*. However, for many plants no corresponding adjectives are attested. If want to express *apple juice* and *cherry blossoms*, what is the best way for them?

- **malĭnus** is attested for *of apple tree* instead of *of apple* or *made of apple*, according to L&S; **cerasĭnus** is *cherry-colored*.
- Smith & Hall suggests neologistic **betulīnus** for **betula** (*birch*). So it is also possible to coin **malīnus** (different from attested **malĭnus**) and **cerasīnus**, is this method widely acceptable?
- Using the genitive case is straightforward, but it is sometimes hard (for me) to determine the plurality. **jus mali** is the juice of *one* apple, and **jus malorum** of some apples, but when we talk about drinking juice, we rarely consider how many apples the juice is made of. The choice of plurality varies among languages. Is there any preference in Latin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the genitive singular of *mālum* seems to be common and perhaps the safest choice. I don't think it necessarily means "the juice/flower of one apple"; I think it can be interpreted as "the juice of the apple" (with the singular used to refer to the fruit in general). Celsus uses the plural *flōrīs* with the singular genitive *Pūnicī mālī* (I'm not sure why the flower gets modified by the genitive of the neuter *pūnicum mālum* rather than that of the feminine *pūnica mālus*).

#### Ancient examples

Here are examples I found of the genitive singular (not of *mālum* by itself, but of compound names built on it) from the PHI corpus:

- Celsus *De Medicina*
- - 5.22.2b.1: "floris Punici mali" -- pomegranate flowers
- - 6.7.2a.3 "dulcis mali Punici sucus", 6.7.2c.1 "sucum Punici mali", 6.7.3b.7 "mali Punici sucum"
- Gaius Plinius Secundus, *Naturalis Historia*:
- - 23.91.1: "decoctum foliorum ambustis et luxatis prodest. ipsa rufant capillum tusa adiecto **struthei mali suco**." -- juice of 'sparrow quince' (?)
- - 30.50.4: "adiecto **flore Punici mali** ex parte dimidia" -- pomegranate flower
- Scribonius Largus, *Compositiones* 85.4: "flos mali granati"

Other examples of genitive singular with plant parts or derivatives:

- Celsus *De Medicina*
- - 4.15.3.5: "lauri bacae, pini flos"
- - 5.27.12b.8: "ius malvae vel ius glandis"
- Gaius Plinius Secundus, *Naturalis Historia*:
- - 25.127.5: "et centaurium potu omnia mala medicamenta exigit per alvum, **vettonicae semen** in mulso aut passo" -- seed of betony
- - 25.128.4, 26.35.4, 26.124.1:  "quinquefolii sucus" --  juice of cinquefoil
- Scribonius Largus, *Compositiones* 85.4 "sucus rosae silvaticae"
- Virgil *Georgica* 2.72: "inseritur vero et nucis arbutus horrida fetu, / et steriles platani malos gessere valentis; / **castaneae** fagus, ornusque incanuit albo / **flore piri**, glandemque sues fregere sub ulmis."

I did find some examples of genitive plural plant names too but they seemed less common:

- Gaius Plinius Secundus, *Naturalis Historia* 17.229.2: "eroduntque frondem, aliae **florem** quoque, **olivarum**"
- Caelius Apicius, *De Re Coquinaria* 5.3.9.3 "cum despumaverit, mittis porrum, coriandrum et **flores malvarum**"

#### Modern examples (scientific Latin)

Here are examples of the genitive singular used in similar contexts in a guide to writing Latin pharmeceutical prescriptions from 1925.

- Syrupus pini cum morphinā
- syrupus scillae
- syrupus ipecacuanhae

(*Lessons in Pharmaceutical Latin and Prescription Writing and Interpretation,* by Hugh Cornelius Muldoon, [page 42](https://books.google.com/books?id=-Bo4AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA42))

Robley Dunglison's *Dictionary of Medical Science*, 21st edition (1893) gives *aurantii flores, oleum aurantii,* and *succus aurantii* as Latin for orange flowers, orange essential oil, and orange juice ([page 240](https://books.google.com/books?id=VmEPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA240)).

Likewise, Thomas Castle's *Lexicon Pharmaceuticum: Or a Pharmaceutical Dictionary, Comprehending the Pharmacopoeias of London, Edinburgh, and Dublin, with a variety of other useful information relative to medicine and pharmacy,* 2nd edition (1828) gives *Citri Aurantii Fructus Succus* as Latin for "Seville Orange Juice" ([page 32](https://books.google.com/books?id=PspEKQZSzxAC&pg=PA32)).

Comment: Gratias ago for your answer. Perhaps I am misled by some random materials which state plural genitive is better.

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian: If these materials are online, it would be interesting to see a link.